# Trouble matching empty line in conditional (python)

Tags: python

My code

```
for line in f:
    if re.match(r'#\s*' + cfgvalue, line):
        print "found it commented out"
    elif line.startswith(cfgvalue):
        print "found it"
```

I then want something to capture if the line is not there.

Sounds simple, but if I place in

```
elif not line.startswith(cfgvalue):
     print "not found"
```

It instead overrides the match section

```
elif line.startswith(cfgvalue)
```

So what would normally be a "found it", comes out as "not found"?

Complete code:

```
for line in f:
    if re.match(r'#\s*' + cfgvalue, line):
        print "found it commented out"
    elif line.startswith(cfgvalue):
        print "found it"
    else:
         if not line.startswith(cfgvalue):
             print "not found"
```

Comment: Is `cfgvalue` an expression or a string literal? If it's a string, why don't you first test whether `cfgvalue in line` before you bother with the RE or startswith?

Comment: https://repl.it/BZ4s/ actually your code produces what needed. As a suggestion is your cfgvalue a string ?

Comment: As a side note: unless you're exercising in building a parser, I suggest that you could solve your particular problem with a [proper](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) [parser](https://github.com/vlasovskikh/funcparserlib) [library](https://github.com/sprymix/parsing) more easily.

Comment: Hi David, yes I tried that, but no matter when that comes in the sequence (the not line.startswith), it is always the conditional that gets matched.

Comment: Like this? https://repl.it/BZ4s/1

Comment: hi oleg, i tried if not line.startswith(str(cfgvalue)): but no difference, it is string, as its an arg

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed exactly: 1: The code you're running that isn't doing what you expect, 2: The input data, 3: The output you're getting, 4: The output you're expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches I can think of. The first is to have a `found` boolean variable which starts out as `False`. If you found it, then set it to `True`:

```
found = False
for line in f:
    if re.match(r'#\s*' + cfgvalue, line):
        print 'found it commented out: {}'.format(line)
    elif line.startswith(cfgvalue):
        print 'found it: {}'.format(line)
        found = True

if found:
    print 'FOUND'
else:
     print 'NOT FOUND
```

Note: in the for loop, only set `found` to `True`. Do not set it to `False`, or its value will be incorrectly overwritten.

The second approach is a little bit more exotic. It relies on the fact that the for loop has an else clause, which will be activated if the loop ends without any break:

```
for line in f:
    if re.match(r'#\s*' + cfgvalue, line):
        print 'found it commented out: {}'.format(line)
    elif line.startswith(cfgvalue):
        print 'found it: {}'.format(line)
        break
else:
    print 'Not found:', cfgvalue
```

In this case, if we find `cfgvalue`, we will immediately break out of the for loop and the else clause will not be executed. If we don't find `cfgvalue`, then the for loop will exit without breaking, thus the else clause will execute.

Comment: found = False worked, many thanks. very simple suggestion, but somehow it negated a race condition or both values were proving to be true.

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether the value exists in the line. If it does, then do your pattern matching, then check the startswith, then check if it exists *anywhere* else.

https://repl.it/BZ4s/2  <-- you can test it, here

```
import re
from cStringIO import StringIO
f = StringIO("AAA - IamOK\n#AAA - IamCOMMENT\nIamOTHER\nAnother line AAA balgh")
cfgvalue = "AAA"

for line in f:
    if cfgvalue in line:
        if re.match(r'#\s*' + cfgvalue, line):
            print "found it commented out"
        elif line[:len(cfgvalue)] == cfgvalue:
            print "found it at start of line"
        else:
            print "found it at {}".format(line.index(cfgvalue))
    else:
        print "not found"
```

Results:

```
found it at start of line
found it commented out
not found
found it at 13
```

This may even help identify whatever specific problem, as I've added a case to check for this `cfgvalue` at *any* position in the line. Perhaps there is whitespace or non-printing characters in which case you might want to do:

```
for line in [l.strip() for l in f]:
```

Comment: This is strange, its not working for me. I checked its a string <type 'str'> not found. I must be missing something else.

Comment: Can you give some example of the data you're trying to test?  Give some example of `f` string, as well as what value `cfgvalue` you're trying to test.

Comment: Hi David, Hai Vu's suggestion fixed it (found = False). Many Many thanks for your efforts to help though.